# Help understanding the meaning of a part in a song's lyric はち切れてしまいそう

Tags: grammar, meaning, verbs, song-lyrics, reading-comprehension

https://www.uta-net.com/song/41088/

I'm having trouble to understand this part from a song's lyric
はち切れてしまいそう

Hope someone can give me a correct definition of this verb.

Comment: The verb is はち切れる. I would suggest you look it up in a dictionary and see if you can make sense out of it.

Comment: https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%AF%E3%81%A1%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> はりつめた心が　はち切れてしまいそう

First off, the verb applies to the "strained heart," and means "[to burst](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%AF%E3%81%A1%E5%88%87%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B)." しまう implies something happened with surprise or unintendedly. [A ます-stem with そう means something "looks like [...]."](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/verb-sou/) And so we have:

> It [will] look like my strained heart will burst.

Based on the lyrics, there is a very strong romanticism going on. Of course, in a more applicable English translation, "look like" may be removed since uncertainty is not common in English songs.